# How to change password for login in SQL Server that was created with MUST_CHANGE option

Tags: c#, sql-server, forms, passwords

I'm writing a Windows Forms application in C# in which users have to connect
to a SQL Server database. The potential users receive randomly built
passwords from the customer and the customers policy enforces that users are required to change the password (SQL Server - option MUST_CHANGE).

I'm having difficulties in providing a function which allows the users
to change the given password on their first attempt to login: every attempt
to connect to SQL Server with the provided credentials leads to
a `SqlException` with error number 18488 stating that the user has to change
the password - which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

I've tried to use:

1. an `ALTER LOGIN` statement as a `SqlCommand`

   ```
   ALTER LOGIN 'someLogin' WITH PASSWORD = 'newPassword', OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldPassword'
   ```
2. a `ServerConnection` with a `Server` and `Login` object issuing a 
   `ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword)` request

   ```
   var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(someSQlConnection);
   serverConnection.Connect();

   var server = new Server(serverConnection);

   var login = new Login(server, 'someLogin') { LoginType = 
   LoginType.SqlLogin };
   login.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
   ```

The Problem is that already the attempt to connect to the SQL Server
fails, the password changing query doesn't even get executed.Anybody can provide a hint how to solve this issue ?

Comment: You need to catch the exception, examine its `Number` property for `18488`, *then* call `login.ChangePassword()`, update your connection string with `newPassword` then try opening the connection again.

Comment: Still the same problem: even if I catch the exception 18488 and try to connect to the server (which I have to do in order to change the password) the connection is refused again with the same exception.

Comment: `ChangePassword()` uses its own internal connection, do not attempt to reconnect before calling it

Comment: The problem is still that I never have a chance to execute ChangePassword() because I need to provide an open connection to the server in order to call that function. But opening that connection already throws another 18488 exception.

Comment: You pass it a connection string and the new password, it should take it from there. (I am talking about the *static* `SqlConnection.ChangePassword()` btw)

Comment: Ok I'll try the static version - that's a valuable hint.

Comment: Just tried it out and I could verify in Management Studio that the password was changed. Pointing out the static version really did it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static [`ChangePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb8k729z(v=vs.110).aspx) method to set the new password:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ChangePassword(someSQlConnection, 
   "new_password");
```

As per documentation:

> This method opens its own connection to the server, requests the
>   password change, and closes the connection as soon as it has
>   completed.